# Should you try to run CUDA C hardware with maximum number thread at all times?

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to find out if there is any other reason than data-path dependency when one would choose to use less than the maximum thread allowed.

Comment: Do you mean maximum threads allowed **for a block**?

Comment: I have voted to reopen because the question does not ask for opinions. Do the people that voted to close know anything about CUDA?

Comment: I'm with Roger. It is a legitimate question, esp. in light of Vasily Volkov's work that shows how performance can be improved by reducing occupancy.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you mean number of threads per block (block size).

The best performance is often attained by using a block size that is lower than the maximum allowed. A GPU contains many different types of hardware resources, such as the resources that keep track of the threads in a block. Each resource is limited and the best performance is achieved when all the resources are utilized as fully as possible. Using the largest block size allowed may cause the other resources to be underutilized.

As kernels become more complex, the maximum block size becomes lower as other resources, such as registers, becomes the limiting factor.

Only threads in the same block can collaborate via shared memory. So, if shared memory is used, the block size is often chosen to fit the algorithm and the data, as well as to maximize the utilization of the other resources.

Memory access patterns can also be affected by the block size. So the block size may be adjusted to generate as many coalesced transactions as possible.

Using smaller blocks with more code in each thread may allow the GPU to find more instruction level parallelism (ILP). So, sometimes, code is adjusted so that each thread performs more work and the block size is lowered.

Comment: Threads are one resource type in the SM. The other are blocks, registers, and shared memory. In a large portion of kernels the maximal performance is achieved at 50-80% occupancy. The more compute heavy the application the less required occupancy. The more latency bound a kernel the more need for higher occupancy. In the end you want to reach the point if possible that on every cycle the warp scheduler can issue a warp. There is also balance required by number of blocks. High number of blocks can lead to instruction address divergence or thrashing of resources in the memory pipeline (MMU).

Comment: Depending on the purposes of the discussion, other limited resources could be global, constant and local memory, L1, L2, texture and instruction caches, bandwidth, cores, LD/ST units, DP units, special function units and schedulers. Depending on the kernel, any of these could become a limiting factor, causing the other resources to go underutilized.